# rangeOfString good but not perfect for my string comparison

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I would like to compare different strings and neither `isEqualToString` nor `rangeOfString` can, in my case, do the work apparently.

For example I have the following strings:

```
s1 = Hello World
s2 = World
```

I now would like to compare these and that works fine with `rangeOfString`, return true, the issue is when i then compare for example this:

```
s1 = helloworldhello
s2 = world
```

this should in my case return false but `rangeOfString` will return true.

The condition are the following:

```
I want to find exact matches.
I want to find similar strings for example "Anna" should be equal to "Hanna Anna"
I do not want to find half words for example "Ann" should not be equal to "Anna"
I do not want to find a part of a word for example "nn" should not be equal to "Anna"
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to search for a string within another string?  Is that right?  That is not "compare".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case you are looking for "World" as a single word use range with a regular expression:

```
NSString *s1;
NSString *s2;
NSRange range;

s1 = @"Hello World";
s2 = @"World";
range = [s1 rangeOfString:s2 options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
NSLog(@"match: %i", range.location != NSNotFound);
```

NSLog output:
    match: 1

```
s1 = @"helloworldhello";
s2 = @"\\bworld\\b";
range = [s1 rangeOfString:s2 options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
NSLog(@"match: %i", range.location != NSNotFound);
```

NSLog output:
    match: 0

```
s1 = @"Hanna Anna";
s2 = @"\\bAnna\\b";
range = [s1 rangeOfString:s2 options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
NSLog(@"match: %i", range.location != NSNotFound);
```

NSLog output:
    match: 1

```
s1 = @"Anna";
s2 = @"\\bAnn\\b";
range = [s1 rangeOfString:s2 options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
NSLog(@"match: %i", range.location != NSNotFound);
```

NSLog output:
    match: 0

```
s1 = @"Anna";
s2 = @"\\bnn\\b";
range = [s1 rangeOfString:s2 options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
NSLog(@"match: %i", range.location != NSNotFound);
```

NSLog output:
    match: 0

The backslash-b means a word boundary and the backslash must be escaped.

Answer (score 2):

Add in a space on either side of s2 if that's really what you're searching for, e.g.

```
s0 = @"hello world";
s1 = @"helloworldhello";

s2 = @" world ";
```

Now do the search, but append a blank space on either end of `s0` and `s1` just to avoid annoying boundary cases.

If you want to be more elegant about it, then look for the string using `rangeOfString:`, and check that there is a nothing (beginning/end of string) or space or punctuation before and after the occurrence of `s2`.